# How can I make a function that execute another function at most N times in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

First of All, I have a Mysql table like this:

`create table t (id int(11) PRIMARY KEY unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(20), age int(10));`

I define a funtion that will create a row in t:

```
(require '[honeysql.core :as sql])

(defn do-something []
    (sql/query {:insert-into  :t
                :values [{:name "name1" :age 10}]})
    (> 3 (rand-int 5)))
```

And now I want to run this function until it return true but at most N times.

This `take-times`code is wrong because repeat will eval the `do-something` function one time and then structure the lazy sequence.

```
(defn take-times []
   (some true? (repeat 5 (do-something))))
```

This `take-times2` will eval the `do-something` 5 times no matter what the `do-something` return.

```
(defn take-times2 []
    (some true? (for [i (range 5)]
                  (do-something))))
```

What should I do if i do not use recursion function and macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
(->> (repeatedly do-something)
     (take 5)
     (some true?))
```

**Update (04.11.2014):**

Since `repeatedly` actually allows for an optional length parameter, this is also fine:

```
(some true? (repeatedly 5 do-something))
```

---

**Example**

```
(defn do-something
  []
  ;; 20% chance of true
  (let [ret (rand-nth [true false false false false])]
    (prn 'hello ret)
    ret))

(defn run
  []
  (->> (repeatedly do-something)
       (take 5)
       (some true?)))

(run)
;; hello false
;; hello false
;; hello true
;; => true

(run)
;; hello false
;; hello false
;; hello false
;; hello false
;; hello false
;; => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function has the reduced option to stop processing a sequence based on a user defined criteria.

Using the random sequence of true and false

```
(defn rand-seq [] (repeatedly #(rand-nth [true false false false false])))
```

Use reduce to build a vector until either a true is found or a maximum number of false values has been reached.

```
(defn at-most-or-true [s max-false]
  (reduce (fn [acc v]
      (if (and (not v) (< (count acc) max-false))
        (conj acc v)
        (reduced acc))) 
    [] s))
```

This can be tested by calling

```
 (at-most-or-true (rand-seq) 5)
```

Comment: this could be simplified with a numeric accumulator `(fn [n v] (if (or v (>= acc max-false)) (reduced v) (inc acc))` with 0 as the initial condition

Comment: oh, the way you use reduced means that the truthy value is never returned

Comment: I wasn't looking at this code as doing anything useful. It was meant as an example that could be redone with sql inserts etc.  The first comment with the numeric accumulator would have been a better example for that purpose.